# Wordpress Admin Query for pages

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to replicate the query that is used in the admin section to display the pages in the exact same order as there. However when I write:

```
$args = array(
'showposts' => '-1',
'post_type' => 'page',
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
);
```

I cannot retrieve the same order as in the admin. I assume there is an inner JOIN query to select based on the parent page and the menu order. I want to replicate the exact same order in a custom meta box and enable the user to say that they are related.

Can somebody help me to achieve this? If it is not possible I can use a custom query to select them directly from the db.

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to make something with the order param like this

$args = array('showposts' => '-1','order'=> 'ASC','post_type' => 'page');

Comment: Hello Yises, unfortunately what you suggested did not display the pages in the same order as Wordpress does. Thanks for trying though. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'authors'      => '',
    'child_of'     => 0,
    'date_format'  => get_option('date_format'),
    'depth'        => 0,
    'echo'         => 1,
    'exclude'      => '',
    'include'      => '',
    'link_after'   => '',
    'link_before'  => '',
    'post_type'    => 'page',
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'show_date'    => '',
    'sort_column'  => 'menu_order, post_title',
    'title_li'     => __('Pages'), 
    'walker'       => ''
  );
  wp_list_pages( $args );
?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

The important part of your question is `sort_column`. This example shows sorting (sort_column) as `menu_order` which will take the WP page order from the backend and sort them by that value. Editing this order is easy with plugins such as the [Simple Page Ordering](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-page-ordering/) one.